# Orca vcc_arrow vcc_bar and vcc_circle

Tags: orcad

I'm drawing a schematic diagram using Orcad. In order to put a power source, I'd like to use one of the vcc, vcc_arrw, vcc_bar and so on. But I have no idea when people use each of them. Could anyone please explain the difference between them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The difference is cosmetic. Use whichever you prefer. Some people like arrows, some people like circles, some people like bars.

Note that whichever you choose, you ought to stick with that one throughout the schematic for consistency.